# How can I acces to my Windows Phone?

Tags: phone, storage, windows-phone

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 and I was wondering if there is an application or something like that to access to my Windows Phone storage. It runs Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the built-in file manager in Ubuntu, 
Just click the top icon on the left panel and type in the search box that shows up "files", and it should be the first icon to show up. You can see it here:

[image]

Click on it and then on the left panel on that window, you should see your windows phone under "devices."

[image]

Also as a side note, you need to have your phone unlocked (as in, on and the password typed in if you have one) to access your storage. If you don't have a password lock on your phone, you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: You should have the rep now :)