# Getting error when plug-in my Windows Phone and i cannot acces my phone files

Tags: windows, lubuntu, phone

i'm new here. I installed Lubuntu to my very old PC and tried to connect my Nokia Lumia 635 (Windows Phone 8.1) but i getting error

Error intializing camera: -53: Could not claim the USB device

I clicking okay it shows that is connected but i can't access files

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: what type of USB connection currently the phone is serving? MTP? or Photo Sharing?

Comment: i don't know where to check it

Comment: look into your Windows phone. Somewhere in the setting I guess.

Comment: take a look [Guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/585904/how-can-i-acces-to-my-windows-phone)

Comment: i'm on Lubuntu not ubuntu

Comment: no different, still Ubuntu based.

Comment: it shows that's connected but there is only 2 folders and there's no files.  Gotta be about 6 folders or more with files

Comment: most of the time, it just a setting on your phone end.

Comment: there's usb settings tab but nothing about mtp or photo sharing

Comment: man, i never use windows phone so i cant imagine if there is any or not.

Comment: comn, help someone.

Comment: It has been a long time but this question is unanswered - I may have a solution for you but I need to know if you're storing your photos in the internal memory or if you're storing them on an SD card? If the former - send 'em to yourself or upload them and download them, sorry. If the latter then enable Mass USB support.

Comment: There's no options to enable Mass USB support in WP. I backup some files from windows when i was installing Ubuntu and transfer them into SD card.